# "Upgrade Required" (ws package) WebSockets with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, websocket

I would like to simply use WebSockets with Node js. I show you my code :

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>WebSockets</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    const WebSocket = require('ws');

    var sock = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5001",{perMessageDeflate:false});

    sock.onopen = function(event){
        alert('Socket connected successfully');
        setTimeout(function(){
            sock.send("Hey !");
        },1000);
    };
    sock.onmessage = function(event){
        console.log(event);
    };

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
var server = require('ws').Server;
var s = new server({ port:5001});
```

I installed the package " ws " to use WebSockets. My first aim is to simply console.log something.

However, I have this error... **" Upgrade Required "** with the status 426 on my GET Request.

(I have been following an online Tutoriel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPLAd-j9tMs) but I get this error...

One should bear in mind that the documentation of this package says : "Note: This module does not work in the browser. The client in the docs is a reference to a back end with the role of a client in the WebSocket communication. Browser clients must use the native WebSocket object."

So it may explain the problem but in this case how to use "the native Websocket object" ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't think this will work in javascript `const WebSocket = require('ws');` you probably need to add script reference like `<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/websockets/library.js"></script>`. Have a look on [**this**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)

Comment: In the Online Tutorial, no path is defined, he used basic script tags and it works perfectly. However I am going to try !

Comment: I got the same error..

Comment: This part `const WebSocket = require('ws');

    var sock = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5001",{perMessageDeflate:false});` is different from the code in the tutorial he simply did `var sock = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5001");`

Comment: Yes I wrote it according to another website, but it does not change anything, i also tried without this line {perMessageDeflate:false}. But something insteresting is (I have just found it on a website ) : "The client establishes a WebSocket connection through a process known as the WebSocket handshake. This process starts with the client sending a regular HTTP request to the server. An Upgrade header is included in this request that informs the server that the client wishes to establish a WebSocket connection." So I think this is a piece of answer I don't know...

Comment: [**Read this**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/426) also. I think you need to upgrade your browser :))))  What browser and version you are using ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150707/discussion-between-e-b-and-codtex).

Comment: One Solution is to use use Socket.IO : https://socket.io/get-started/chat/